# Creating my own Helper in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

Just learning PHP and Codeigniter at the moment and I'm stuck on a trivial one. I created a helper to calculate a percentage of two numbers:

```
    # Below is the Helper

    function percentage($num1 = NULL, $num2 = NULL)
    {           
        $res = $num1/$num2*100;

        return $res;
    }
```

Now I call the helper function in the controller using the below code:

```
    public function tester()
    {
        $this->load->helper('sums_helper');

        $num1 = 36;
        $num2 = 137;

        percentage($num1, $num2);

        // Need to print the result here.
        // Tried: $percentage->$res;

    }
```

I call the function and pass over the two required variables however cannot print the result. Any suggestions would be greatfuly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!! Niall

Comment: Just assign function return value to variable. `$result = percentage(1, 2)`

Comment: Thank you so much, That worked perfectly. could you paste it in as an answer so you can get the bounty and I can close the question? :)

Comment: Wouldn't the proper OOP way be $result = $this->sums_helper->percentage($num1, $num2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign function return value to the variable:

```
$result = percentage($num1, $num2);
```

so you can print it:

```
print_r($result);
```